# Conditional uninstall of OSGi feature

Tags: continuous-integration, osgi, jbossfuse

I have a continuous integration for building OSGi features for jboss-fuse. After feature is built (and published to artifact repository), SSH to OSGi console is established and following commands executed:

```
features:uninstall xyz
features:install xyz
```

This works when xyz is installed, otherwise it ends with obvious failure:

```
Error executing command: Feature named 'xyz' is not installed
```

Is there any way how to conditionaly uninstall given feature? For example using `shell:if` commands? Or other way how to reinstall given feature automatically?

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you use a part of Karaf to install your feature in the jboss container.

1. You could inject the kar service (org.apache.karaf.kar.KarService) into your test and use the install/uninstall features from there.
2. If you are working remotly (which I think you are), you could use the JMX MBean org.apache.karaf:type=feature,name=root to remotely install/uninstall your feature.